# backlinks from the same ip address with different domain name is legal?

Tags: seo, google, backlinks

Please i have a question in relation with SEO,
I have a lot of website hosted in a dedicated server with one ip adresse but with multiple domain name's 'any website have a domain name'.
and i want to generate backlink's from this website to rich my SEO, my question is if i generate backlinks from this websites is legal or not.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's legal but it's not going to improve your site rankings as much as a completely different IP chain or website on a totally different server. I have a lot of websites and try to use different servers for a lot of my domains. This way when you make back links they have more weight than back links from the same IP address with different domains.

There is no penalty for back linking sites with the same IP or IP chain but if you do too many of them then it could hurt your rankings